# How to limit PHP stack trace output

Tags: php

I have an app that sometimes dumps a stack trace. It seems that something has changed somewhere and now the trace contains really massive lines (e.g. 36k chars long) due to dumping of complex arguments.

There's several questions on here about how to increase the verbosity of stack dumps, but can't find any for shortening!

I'm on PHP 7.4

I'd like to see argument values in function calls, but if it's an object or deeply nested array, I don't want the whole thing. Is that possible?

Comment: ^ Just lower the number instead of increasing them

Comment: Re linked to answer: `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` seems to be the *nested* levels that are included in a stack trace and `xdebug.var_display_max_children` seems to be the children of the particular object/array. I think that this means that a settings of 2, 128 respectively, would mean up to 128^2 possible items received. (possibly ^3, if depth 2 means grand children.)